# only first contact gets deleted

Tags: java, serialization

this is my code snippet.
data is a 2D array of type Object.I have previously saved data in JTable.Now i have written
code to delete entry.But if go by this code only first entry gets deleted from JTable.

I am unable to understand the reason behind this.

please help me out in this.

-snippet:

```
public void deleteActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  String delname=tf4.getText();
  int c=0;
  try {
    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.txt"));
    data=(Object[][])ois.readObject(); 

    for(;;c++) {
      String x=(String)data[c][0];
      if(x.equals(delname)) {
        System.out.println("if working");
        data[c][0]=null;
        data[c][1]=null;
        data[c][2]=null;
        try {
          ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data.txt"));
          oos.writeObject(data);
        } catch(Exception exc) {
          System.out.println("error deleting data from"+" "+c+" row");
        }
        c++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"contact deleted");
        try {
          ObjectInputStream oist=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.txt"));
          data=(Object[][])oist.readObject();       
          JTable tb=new JTable(data,headers);
          ObjectOutputStream oost=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("contacts.txt"));
          oost.writeObject(tb);
        } catch(Exception exc) {
          System.out.println("error updating after deleting");
        }

      }
      else
        System.out.println("else working");


    }
  } catch(Exception exc) {
    System.out.println("error reading data.txt for deleting");
  }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an actual debugger?

Comment: Do you get any error messages here?

Answer (score 1):

After properly indenting your code, it becomes more obvious ...

- You are re-creating (and re-reading) the file in your loop, instead of after it - why?
- You are writing out a new JTable object after every deletion.

  - Why writing it out at all?
  - How are you reading them?
- Additionally, you have two `c++` inside your loop, so the second element of the array is skipped.
- Third, in case of exceptions you simply go on (and even don't print out the whole exception).

Comment: @Brian: ... and by 9 seconds on formatting the source-code in the question. Your variant is better, though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that - the message flashed at the top just as I was hitting the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can only run this algorithm to delete once before getting a NullPointerException

If in a previous run you deleted any item, you'll get a NPE each time you compare it.

> String x=(String)data[c][0];
>
> if(x.equals(delname)) {

It would be safer if you do delname.equals(x) (assuming you have checked that delname is not null before) or check for x == null in the if before equals.

A better solution would be, after the loop, copying the array to a new one without the deleted elements. Even better, after deserializing the object, pass it to a List class and work with it, and only pass it back to array in order to serialize it when you are finished with the program (or directly serialize the List, if you can).

That said, I cannot find anything that would work with the first element but not the others. Maybe it is that when you run your test you first try with the first element and then, after corrupting the array so you'll have a NPE, you test the other elements.

EDIT: Didn't see the extra c++ (probably it was a while before?). Only will work with odd element indexes.